# How to replace text in text file using bat file script?

Tags: windows, regex, batch-file, replace

So I want to create a script that takes 3 arguments: path to file, exact word to replace, and with what to replace it. How to create such thing?

Generally I want it to have an API like this:

```
script.bat "C:/myTextDoc.xml" "_WORD_TO_REPLACE_" "WordTo Use"
```

Answer (score 7):

I have written something like 2 batch scripts in my life, but here's how to take input from the command line:

```
script.bat filepath find replace
%1 = filepath, %2 = find, %3 = replace
```

To do replacement, do something like:

```
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %1|find /n /v """') do (
set "line=%%B"
if defined line (
    call set "line=echo.%%line:%~2=%~3%%"
    for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

(taken directly from the link posted by @russ, with the variable numbers changed.)

I think this should work for you.

Answer (score 7):

Use **fnr** utility its better than other famous utility since it can search and replace based on regular expressions. Also for the UI lovers you can configure options in UI and it can generate command line string which can then be used in your script. Very easy to use even as command line stirng.

Find it here http://findandreplace.codeplex.com/

Also it is single exe without any dependicies, so easy to use.

Example:

```
fnr --cl --dir "" --fileMask "hibernate.*" --useRegEx 
      --find "find_str_expression" --replace "replace_string"
```

Comment: The statement "it is a single exe without any dependencies" is false. FNR is a .NET application and therefore requires at least a specific .NET version on the client machine. Source: http://findandreplace.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: An empty --dir parameter is not be accepted by the current (1.7) version. Giving the current work directory will do the job though: --dir %CD%

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search found this:

http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FindAndReplace